# How to hide a activity class for production build

Tags: android

I'm doing some action on dev/qa environment, so I've a activity called *DexActivity.kt*, now I dont want *DexActivity* to shown in production environment when I do PenTest.

```
 Q. Can this activity hidden in production build, if yes how?
```

Comment: How is it currently accessed?

Comment: From other apps?  Sure, just don't export it in the manifest.  From the same app?  Not really.  What you can do is on the first line of onCreate check if its prod and if so immediately return.  It would technically be launched but never show itself.  That's proabbly your best compromise

Answer (score 0):

You should create two build variants. A `production` one and a `dev/qa`, which I'm calling `debug` in the following.

Basically it's as simple as creating a similar file structure in your project as this:

```
src
├── debug
│   └── kotlin
│       └── package
│           └── BaseActivity.kt
└── main
    └── kotlin
        └── package
            ├── (BaseAbstractActivity.kt)
            └── BaseActivity.kt
```

You add all the relevant QA-code to the `BaseActivity` inside `debug`, together with the rest of the production code. The `BaseActivity` inside `main` only contains the production code.

In case this creates a lot of duplicated code, you could also just create **a single** `BaseAbstractActivity` inside `main` as `abstract class`. Now, inside both `debug` and `main` create two files `BaseActivity`, which inherit from `BaseAbstractActivity`. The `main` one doesn't modify the base class, where the `debug` one adds the QA code.

Your Gradle build will now automatically produce two APK files: Debug and production.

There's more you can configure when using build variants, like specifying different namespaces, so that both app variants can be installed on a single device in the same time.
Here`s the full documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants